# Create a dictionary by zipping together two lists of uneven length

Tags: python, list, dictionary, zip

I have two lists different lengths, L1 and L2. L1 is longer than L2. I would like to get a dictionary with members of L1 as keys and members of L2 as values.

As soon as all the members of L2 are used up. I would like to start over and begin again with L2[0].

```
L1 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']    
L2 = ['1', '2', '3']    
D = dict(zip(L1, L2))    
print(D)
```

As expected, the output is this:

```
{'A': '1', 'B': '2', 'C': '3'}
```

What I would like to achieve is the following:

```
{'A': '1', 'B': '2', 'C': '3', 'D': '1', 'E': '2'}
```

Comment: Curious as to the reason for the close votes. What about this question is too broad? If it is because the OP hasn't offered any solution, then I can understand OP may not have the first clue where to begin. Based on their explanation of the question, it does not seem like they could have googled for "cycle", "circular", or other similar keywords that would have led to a solution.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) to cycle around to the beginning of `L2`:

```
from itertools import cycle
dict(zip(L1, cycle(L2)))
# {'A': '1', 'B': '2', 'C': '3', 'D': '1', 'E': '2'}
```

---

In your case, concatenating `L2` with itself also works.

```
# dict(zip(L1, L2 * 2))
dict(zip(L1, L2 + L2))
# {'A': '1', 'B': '2', 'C': '3', 'D': '1', 'E': '2'}
```

Answer (score 25):

Use [itertools.cycle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle):

```
from itertools import cycle

L1 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
L2 = ['1', '2', '3']

result = dict(zip(L1, cycle(L2)))

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
{'E': '2', 'B': '2', 'A': '1', 'D': '1', 'C': '3'}
```

As an alternative you could use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) and index `L2` modulo the length of `L2`:

```
result = {v: L2[i % len(L2)] for i, v in enumerate(L1)}
print(result)
```

Answer (score 16):

`cycle` is fine, but I shall add this modulo based approach:

```
{x: L2[i % len(L2)] for i, x in enumerate(L1)]}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can also use a [`collections.deque()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) to create an circular FIFO queue:

```
from collections import deque

L1 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']    
L2 = deque(['1', '2', '3'])

result = {}
for letter in L1:
    number = L2.popleft()
    result[letter] = number
    L2.append(number)

print(result)
# {'A': '1', 'B': '2', 'C': '3', 'D': '1', 'E': '2'}
```

Which pops the left most item currently in `L2` and appends it to the end once the number is added to the dictionary.

**Note:** Both [`collections.deque.popleft()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque.popleft) and [`collections.deque.append()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque.append) are O(1) operations, so the above is still O(N), since you need to traverse all the elements in `L1`.

Answer (score 7):

Other option **without dependencies** with good old `for` loop:

```
D = {}
for i, e in enumerate(L1):
  D[e] = L2[i%len(L2)]

D #=> {'A': '1', 'B': '2', 'C': '3', 'D': '1', 'E': '2'}
```

Or just:

```
{ e: L2[i%len(L2)] for i, e in enumerate(L1) }
#=> {'A': '1', 'B': '2', 'C': '3', 'D': '1', 'E': '2'}
```

Comment: Isn't that already here? https://stackoverflow.com/a/54095907/4909087 and also in another answer.